# Angular 8: Getting error on console ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when *ngIf is used

Tags: angular, angular8

I have 2 components inside a wrapper, and wrapper has fixed height.
ToggleComponent has height css property bound to height field and a button which changes height field.
TestComponent takes rest of the height. It has test attribute bound to its clientHeight .
Focus is on the DOM binding to something that would change from other component by its binding, that is why i use clientHeight. If there is *ngIf directive on TestComponent, when ToggleComponent.height is changed, ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError occurs.

Error:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'test: 200'. Current value: 'test: 100'.
    at viewDebugError (core.js:20440)
    at expressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (core.js:20428)
    at checkBindingNoChanges (core.js:20530)
    at checkNoChangesNodeInline (core.js:23403)
    at checkNoChangesNode (core.js:23390)
    at debugCheckNoChangesNode (core.js:23994)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:23922)
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (testChild.html:2)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23911)
    at checkNoChangesView (core.js:23289)
```

Comment: plz post your code.

Comment: Sounds like you are changing the `ngIf` in a subscribe method during `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add such code:

`import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';`

Your class must implement `OnAfterViewChecked`

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewChecked()
{
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

But for the best answer, show your code.